# Java not recognized but classpath and path are set

Tags: java

I downloaded java(jdk 7),Eclipse and Tomcat 7 in my system, I did few programs and got the output too but all of a sudden it says java and javac are not recognized as internal or external command.I uninstalled everything and re-installed but still not working.I did set the classpath too.When i say echo %classpath%, it gives me the the right classpath.

Comment: You probably have to set JAVA_HOME or set up the locating of your Java runtime at your IDE.

Comment: You haven't had to set the CLASSPATH for Java installations since about 1998, but you do have to have `java.exe` available on the PATH.

Comment: And what is your question?